# Bookmarklet link in Markdown document

Tags: markdown, bookmarklet

How can I include a bookmarklet in a Markdown parsed document? Is there any "tag" for markdown that basically says "don't parse this"??

For example you could have something like:

```
<a href="javascript:function my_bookmarklet()
                {alert('Hello World');}
                my_bookmarklet();">Hello</a>
```

But if I try to past the javascript from that into a link in markdown like this:

```
[Hello World!](javascript:function my_bookmarklet(){alert('Hello World');}my_bookmarklet();)
```

You get a messed up link, like below.

[Hello World!](javascript:function my_bookmarklet(){alert('Hello World');}my_bookmarklet();)

Is there anyway around this?

And no, I'm not trying to put malicious bookmarklets in SO or anything, but I want to use markdown for my site and would like to post some bookmarklets I wrote.

Edit:  I thought I had the answer...but now it seems I don't quite have it.

This seems to work great in WMD and showdown, but in the Markdown.php editor, it does not.  Anyone have experience with Markdown.php specifically?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Markdown will leave any HTML alone, so you can just enter

```
<a href="javascript:function my_bookmarklet()
                {alert('Hello World');}
                my_bookmarklet();">Hello</a>
```

<del>and get Hello.</del> *Edit: No longer works on SO, which is a good thing*

You can also escape special characters with a backslash (in this case it's seeing the ")"s in your Javascript as the end of the URL) and the link syntax will work:

```
[Hello](javascript:function my_bookmarklet(\){alert('Hello World'\);}my_bookmarklet(\);)
```

<del>gives [Hello](javascript:function my_bookmarklet(){alert('Hello World');}my_bookmarklet();)</del>

Comment: The default behaviour of Markdown is to leave inline HTML alone so the examples should work if you're using Markdown on your own site. However, any site displaying user-submitted content should be restricting the HTML that it allows through to protect against XSS. It's a small step from that `alert('Hello World')` example to hijacking other people's SO accounts. Looking back, I'm surprised that those examples originally worked in my answer. They really shouldn't have, and don't any more.

Answer (score 8):

```
[Hello World!][1]
[1]:javascript:alert('Hello World')
```

Comment: Yes! This is how you do it! Also works when formatted with the link on the next line (like `prettier` might do because of a long link.
This also works in MDX documents where for some reason `<a>` tags does not work.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a very old question, but (in case someone else finds their way here, as I did), if you url-encode your script, it will work.

For example:

```
[Hello World](javascript:%28function%28%29%7Balert%28%22Hello%20World%22%29%7D%29%28%29%3B)
```

And of course, as mentioned above, it does not work here, on SO.

Note: Some url-encoders will replace space (" ") with a "+", which works fine for regular urls, but not JS code, spaces should be replaced with "%20"

**EDIT**: This doesn't seem to be universally true. I suppose the specific markdown parser makes the final call here. But this works for me in more places where markdown is used.